# Translating tuple to array?

Tags: swift

I'm accessing a `C` language struct in my Swift project that stores data as a tuple and I want to iterate over it.

```
let tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

AFAIK, I have two options. The first is to mirror the tuple so that I can map its reflection into an array:

```
let tupleMirror = Mirror(reflecting: tuple)
let tupleArray = tupleMirror.children.map({ $0.value }) as! [Int]
```

And the second option is to translate it into an array using manual memory management with something like an unsafe buffer pointer. From all that I've read, it's usually suggested to avoid the manual-memory route if possible and `Mirror` certainly appears to do that. Is mirroring a safe/reliable way to convert a tuple to an array? Or is there a better approach to translating the tuple into an array or even iterating over the tuple itself?

Comment: Is your tuple always of arbitrary length? Why do you want to keep it as a tuple? Why don't use array from the beginning?

Comment: @MaximKosov The length is constant. And I don't want to keep it as a tuple. In my example, I've translated it to an array. And modifying the C code is not an option (third-party dependency).

Comment: So, if the length is constant, say 5, can you just write a regular function? Like `let arr = [tuple.0, tuple.1, ...]`?

Comment: @MaximKosov I could in this case but assuming the tuple wasn't a constant size? There are a number of structs I haven't gotten to yet and I can't assume they will all be constant.

Comment: Looks like on the apple forums they suggest to use `UsafeBufferPointer`. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72120

Comment: I don't think tuple could be not constant size, to be honest

Comment: Either way, I don't think the reflection is good approach. Personally I'd just write things manually (as in my earlier comment)

Comment: Please show us the C language struct we're talking about. No need to talk about modifying it, we understand you can't, but there is no such thing as a C tuple so please make clear why a Swift tuple is how you're starting. There may be a better way to access this struct from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mirror` is fiiiiiiiiiiiiine.

```swift
extension Array {
  init?<Subject>(mirrorChildValuesOf subject: Subject) {
    guard let array = Mirror(reflecting: subject).children.map(\.value) as? Self
    else { return nil }

    self = array
  }
}
```

```swift
  XCTAssertEqual(
    Array( mirrorChildValuesOf: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ),
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  )

  XCTAssertNil(
    [Int]( mirrorChildValuesOf: (1, 2, "3", 4, 5) )
  )
```